# FLANN hiearchical kmeans How to determine which vector is assigned to which cluster?

Tags: k-means, hierarchical-clustering, flann

Hi everyone i am new to FLANN,

I would like to perform a hiearchical kmeans clustering using FLANN,
how can i determine which vector belongs to which cluster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here are some links with plenty of info, a good read may answer your question. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html -- https://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf